# how to create list onClick

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create list of UL views, and add them a specific onclick function. this is my code:

```
function createList(divName) {

  var divName = document.getElementById(divName);
  for (var i in myListOfObjects) {
    // create an arbitrary ul element
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var s = myListOfObjects[i]; //get specific object (JSON object)
    var subject = document.createElement('li'),
      subjectContent = document.createTextNode("someText"); // subject
    subject.appendChild(subjectContent);
    ul.appendChild(subject);
    ul.onclick = function() {
      //pass  the specific TEXT from the specific JSON object to the next page.
      window.location.href = "NewPage.html" +
        "?specificText=" + JSON.stringify(s);
    };
    // append the created ul element above to the  div element                
    div.appendChild(ul);
  }

}
```

My problem is : When I run the function , click fucntion Get the same " TEXT " for all objects in " MyListOfObjects " ( the text is the last object "s" text its mean that the last object is overrite the first ) , I checked the text value in this list is not the same , so how can I know what is causing the problem foreign this ? And how to solve this problem .

Thanks !

Comment: Can you specify whats present in "myListOfObjects"? Also I am not sure why have you tagged Java with this question.

Comment: Thank you I edited the Tags, myListOfObject is a list of object that every one object have fields like TEXT, SUBJECT and more than, I want that when the user is clicked on one ul (its mean one object in the list that shown) the specific object will pass to the next page and in the next page i will show the full fields of this object.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you please post an image of what you rough image of exactly what you wanna accomplish? Also post the sample object that is assigned to myListOfObject.

Comment: Im new in this site can you give me your email to send the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus I am underestanding, you need a UL tag that has li tags inside in based on specified Object list(myObjectList). when you click on every li your page redirect to specified page based on object.
try it code:

```js
var myListOfObjects = [
        {'TEXT': 'a1', 'ID': 0},
        {'TEXT': 'a3', 'ID': 1},
        {'TEXT': 'a2', 'ID': 2}
    ];//sample object list

    function createList(divName) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divName);
        // a ul element has many li elements.
        //this line out of for-loop. only one ul is enough.
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        var i = 0;//counter of
        for (var objId in myListOfObjects) {
            var obj = myListOfObjects[objId];
            var subject = document.createElement('li');
            subjectContent = document.createTextNode("someText"); // subject
            subject.id = 'li_' + i;
            subject.setAttribute('myId', i);// specified related object
            subject.appendChild(subjectContent);

            subject.onclick = function (event) {
                var index = this.getAttribute('myId');
                obj = myListOfObjects[index];
                loc = "NewPage.html" + "?specificText=" + JSON.stringify(obj['TEXT']);
                window.location.href = loc;
                //remove comment to test
                alert(loc);

            };
            ul.appendChild(subject);
            i++;
        }
        div.appendChild(ul);

    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but its still get the last object when click on some  ul,

Comment: I dont want to put many li inside one ul, because every item in this list need to includ many lines of data and the click function need to be on the frame not on every li, do you understand my meaning? sorry about the english...

Comment: Its Working? As You need?

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a div DOM object but assign it to the variable `divName`. Then, later, you use variable `div` which was never assigned.

Try this instead:

```
function createList(divName) {

  var div = document.getElementById(divName);
  for (var i in myListOfObjects) {
    // create an arbitrary ul element
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var s = myListOfObjects[i]; //get specific object (JSON object)
    var subject = document.createElement('li'),
      subjectContent = document.createTextNode(s); // subject
    subject.appendChild(subjectContent);
    ul.appendChild(subject);
    ul.onclick = function() {
      //pass  the specific TEXT from the specific JSON object to the next page.
      window.location.href = "NewPage.html" +
        "?specificText=" + JSON.stringify(s["TEXT"]);
    };
    // append the created ul element above to the  div element                
    div.appendChild(ul);
  }
}
```